# HDP + ambari + yarn node lables and HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hdp

we have Hadoop cluster ( HDP 2.6.4 cluster with ambari , with 5 datanodes machines )

we are using spark streaming application (spark 2.1 run over Hortonworks 2.6.x )

the current situation is that spark streaming applications runs on all datanodes machines

as maybe some are know by yarn node labels we can enable spark streaming application to run only on the first **2** data-nodes machines

so if for example - we configured *yarn node labels* on the first **2** data-nodes machines then on the other 3 data-nodes machines spark application will not run because yarn node lables is disabled

**my question is** - is it possible *by yarn node labels* also to disable the HDFS on the 3 last data-nodes machines , ( in order to avoid any replica of HDFS on the 3 last data-nodes )

reference - http://crazyadmins.com/configure-node-labels-on-yarn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [decomission a datanode](http://www.hadooplessons.info/2017/12/decommissioning-datanodes-hadoop-cluster-hdpca.html). If you do this, then by definition, it is not part of HDFS, meaning you're basically halting HDFS services and removing them from the cluster, which is **not** the same as limiting which jobs get ran on them (e.g. via YARN Node Labels)

Node Labels control which NodeManagers run code, not directly related to DataNodes.

You could have NodeManangers running outside of DataNodes, but that defeats the purpose of using HDFS's feature of "moving compute to the data", thus causing jobs to run slower

Comment: I am fully agree with you ,  but any documentation that said "Node Labels control which NodeManagers run code, not DataNodes." ,?

Comment: NodeLabels are a YARN feature, not HDFS, therefore DataNodes play no part of that

Comment: yes fully agree , but please understand my bad situation , I need to convinced my manager that yarn node labels are not relevant for hdfs -:(

Comment: They are called "YARN Node Labels" :) The similar feature of HDFS would be [Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html)

Comment: but HDFS Federation isnt supported by HDP as I understand

Comment: There is no view in Ambari to manage it, so that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220329/discussion-between-jessica-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: So just to be complete what @OneCricketeer is correct factually, you can however decommision a datanode.  This is equivalent to what OneCicketeer said but does give jessica a tool to speak to the manger.  It would also be what you need to do, just trying to help round out the conversation for other in the future.